# Analysis of a campaign holdout experiment

Tags: experiment-design

We have an experiment where we are splitting an audience into 4 equal groups of 2000 customers each. 3 will receive an email but 1 group won't received anything. The goal is to test if they will initiate a first payment event.

We expect the data at the end to look like this:

| Groups | Audience size | Event count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Group 1 | 2000 | 50 |
| Group 2 | 2000 | 68 |
| Group 3 | 2000 | 32 |
| control (no email) | 2000 | 6 |

The questions we are trying to answer are:

- Is sending an email a better intervention relative to not sending any email?
- What's the lift/incremental benefit of sending an email relative to not sending one for each variant (if any)

I want to know what's the best (or most straightforward) way  to analysis this "experiment" and answer these two questions. I have seen poisson regression as a suggested way but I am not familiar with the technique. I did some reading and found that Kruskal–Wallis could be used for this kind of setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is typically analyzed as a logistic regression because response vs. non-response is a binomial variable, and the email is the treatment.

$$logit(y_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i1} + \beta_2 x_{i2} + \beta_3 x_{i3} + \epsilon_i$$

where $x_{i1} = 1$ if the treated person is in group 1, 0 otherwise, and $E(\epsilon_i) = 0$

The first test is one of asking if there is any effect (similar to the overall F-test in a linear model).

$$H_0:  p_{CTRL} = p_1 = p_2 = p_3$$

The test of the significance of $\beta_1$ is a test of the difference between the effect of the treatment due to group 1 and control.  Because of the logistic transform, this is a comparison of the log-odds of the group vs. control.

$$H_0: ln \left( \frac{\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}}{\frac{p_{CTRL}}{1-p_{CTRL}}} \right) = 0$$

R code follows:

```r
> X <- data.frame(trt = rep(c("G1", "G2", "G3", "CTRL"), each = 2000),
+                 y = c(rep(1, 50), rep(0, 2000-50),
+                       rep(1, 68), rep(0, 2000-68),
+                       rep(1, 32), rep(0, 2000-32),
+                       rep(1, 6),  rep(0, 2000-6)))
> 
> m1 <- glm(y ~ trt, data = X, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
> m0 <- glm(y ~ 1, data = X, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
> 
> # is the response different for at least one group?
> #  H0:  p1 = p2 = p3 = p_CTRL
> anova(m1, m0, test = "LRT")

Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: y ~ trt
Model 2: y ~ 1
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
1      7996     1471.0                          
2      7999     1537.4 -3  -66.402 2.514e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> # reject the null hypothesis at the 0.05 alpha level
> 
> summary(m1)

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ trt, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = X)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.2630  -0.2250  -0.1796  -0.0775   3.4086  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -5.8061     0.4088 -14.201  < 2e-16 ***
trtG1         2.1426     0.4332   4.946 7.58e-07 ***
trtG2         2.4593     0.4271   5.759 8.47e-09 ***
trtG3         1.6871     0.4460   3.783 0.000155 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1537.4  on 7999  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1471.0  on 7996  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1479

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 8

> 
> # Example:  Point Estimate of odds(G1)/odds(CTRL)
> exp(coef(m1)[2]) 

   trtG1 
8.521367 

> 50/6 * (2000-6)/(2000-50)

[1] 8.521368

> 
> # you need to decide the alpha level for these multiple comparisons based on your philosophy on Type I error
> 
> # test of G1 vs CTRL
> summary(m1)$coefficients[2,]
Estimate   Std. Error      z value     Pr(>|z|) 
2.142577e+00 4.332043e-01 4.945880e+00 7.580047e-07 
> 
> # test of G2 vs CTRL
> summary(m1)$coefficients[3,]
    Estimate   Std. Error      z value     Pr(>|z|) 
2.459335e+00 4.270558e-01 5.758815e+00 8.470666e-09 
> 
> # test of G3 vs CTRL
> summary(m1)$coefficients[4,]
    Estimate   Std. Error      z value     Pr(>|z|) 
1.6871013024 0.4459947333 3.7827830163 0.0001550846 
>
```

##### Supplement

There are other methods of analysis that can be chosen.  It is important that the method of analysis be specified prior to the experiment.

$H_o$: There is no relationship between the rows and columns of a two-way table of results

```r
> # test for association between rows (treatments) and columns (response)
> fisher.test(matrix(c(50, 2000-50, 68, 2000-68, 32, 2000-32, 6, 2000-6), ncol=2, 
+                    byrow=TRUE, dimnames = list(c("G1", "G2", "G3", "CTRL"),
+                                                c("Respond", "Non-Respond"))))

    Fishers Exact Test for Count Data

data:  matrix(c(50, 2000 - 50, 68, 2000 - 68, 32, 2000 - 32, 6, 2000 - 6), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(c("G1", "G2", "G3", "CTRL"), c("Respond", "Non-Respond")))
p-value = 3.458e-14
alternative hypothesis: two.sided

> 
> # test for a two dimensional contingency table
> chisq.test(matrix(c(50, 2000-50, 68, 2000-68, 32, 2000-32, 6, 2000-6), ncol=2, 
+                   byrow=TRUE, dimnames = list(c("G1", "G2", "G3", "CTRL"),
+                                               c("Respond", "Non-Respond"))))

    Pearsons Chi-squared test

data:  matrix(c(50, 2000 - 50, 68, 2000 - 68, 32, 2000 - 32, 6, 2000 -     6), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(c("G1", "G2",     "G3", "CTRL"), c("Respond", "Non-Respond")))
X-squared = 54.917, df = 3, p-value = 7.152e-12
```

$H_o$: Pairwise comparisons of $p_i = p_{ctrl}$

For pairwise comparisons, if they are done on their own, I recommend testing with a Bonferroni-corrected p-value

```r
> # three pairwise tests of two proportions (bonferroni corrected p-values should be used)
> prop.test(c(50, 6), c(2000, 2000))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(50, 6) out of c(2000, 2000)
X-squared = 33.487, df = 1, p-value = 7.175e-09
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.01424999 0.02975001
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
 0.025  0.003 

> prop.test(c(68, 6), c(2000, 2000))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(68, 6) out of c(2000, 2000)
X-squared = 51.232, df = 1, p-value = 8.209e-13
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.02220366 0.03979634
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
 0.034  0.003 

> prop.test(c(32, 6), c(2000, 2000))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(32, 6) out of c(2000, 2000)
X-squared = 16.605, df = 1, p-value = 4.603e-05
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.006501261 0.019498739
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
 0.016  0.003
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer and the code.

Comment: I will need to go take sometime to go thorough this, I understand the mechanics but not sure I get the theory. I had a quick follow-up/side note question. As an alternative, would it be appropriate to do a proportions test (chi square test) and then odds ratio tests between the control and each variant?

Comment: Short answer is yes.  I added those tests to the answer.

Comment: Hi @R Carnell, following up on the above. Are the chi-square and prop test mutually exclusive or do I need to run the chi square first and if it's significant then I can proceed with proportion tests?

Comment: @Anas They are not mutually exclusive.  You can run the chi-square test and then proceed with multiple comparisons.  As I suggested, you should consider performing the multiple comparisons with a Bonferoni adjustment so that you control your Type I error rate.

Comment: I see thanks a lot for the clarification! So if I run the chi-square test and it's not significant I shouldn't proceed with multiple comparisons with a Bonferoni adjustment. I should only do adjusted multiple comparisons if first the chi-square turns out significant.